Bluetooth Rapid Disconnection for BLE device when pairing it with One Plus Nord Android Version 12
I have a smart ring BLE device, which I pair with android app and perform communication with it.
To perform communication various command need to send at various characteristic to recieve data. This is working very fine with most of the android phones with latest android version.
But problem I am facing with One Plus Nord Android version 12, BLE device get pair with Android app, but on sending command to BLE device, it is disconnecting itself with in a second.
If I don't send the command to BLE device, then it remain connected. Same BLE devive if pair with other Android models, it is working very fine on sending commands and fetching data. I am facing this issue with 5% of Android devices.
What I did to resolve it

Network and Bluetooth Reset
Bluetooth Cache clear from system app
I tried by changing connection interval, slave latency and supervisor timeout in ring side.

After few testings with BLE device from same phone here are few observations :
Multiple UUID are defined for BLE device on which we receive data. I am enabling notification for these UUID, whenever there is change in byte data It will trigger.
fun queueSetNotificationForCharacteristic(
    gatt: BluetoothGatt,
    characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic
) {
    val ghattQueueItem = GhattQueueItem(
        characteristic = characteristic,
        enabled = true,
        ghatt = gatt,
        ghattQueueItemType = SUBSCRIBE_CHARACTERISTIC
    )
    setNotificationForCharacteristic(ghattQueueItem)
}

 private fun setNotificationForCharacteristic(ghattQueueItem: GhattQueueItem) {
    ghattQueueItem.ghatt?.let { gatt ->
        ghattQueueItem.characteristic?.let { characteristic ->
            gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true)
            // This is specific to Heart Rate Measurement.
            val descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU){
                gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor, BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE)
            }else{
                descriptor.value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE
                gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor)
            }
        }
    }
}

Now for ONE PLUS NORD phone Enbling notification after sending command to BLE device is working fine and smart ring is not disconnecitng
But enabling notification before and send command after that is causing disconnection issue
This process working successfully for most of the android devices but not for this one.
I got some clue, but still not able to figure out solution for this one need help from here.
Thanks

I think your question is a duplicate of this one. Are you a colleague or is this your second account? However, my comment on the first question applies here. Use Android's built-in Bluetooth debugging capabilities to find the problem.

Does this answer your question? Android BLE unexpectedly and repeatedly reconnects to peripheral

Hi Maven, your answer doesn't seems relevant to my question. My BLE device disconnecting after sending command to it.

Edited my question after some tests.
